# What are the consequences of moving a folder and reverting that move in SVN?

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, tortoisesvn, revert

We accidentally moved a major folder in our SVN repository with a long history. It happened because we selected "move and rename" instead of "copy and rename" to create a new branch by accident. The operation shows up in TortoiseSVN like this:

| Path | Action | Copy from Path | Revision |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /branches/feature/NameOfFeatureBranch | Added | /trunk/TheFolder | 10000 |
| /trunk/TheFolder | Deleted |  |  |

Afterwards, the folder was added back:

| Path | Action | Copy from Path | Revision |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /trunk/TheFolder | Added | /branches/feature/NameOfFeatureBranch | 10001 |

The history (e.g. in a blame) is still all there, but Tortoise SVN stops looking past the problematic revision if "Stop on copy/rename" is enabled. We can live with that. The main question is: Are there any other consequences that we are not yet aware of? Also: Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let anyone know who comes across this issue: After several weeks of working with the described state, we could not find any issues (besides the minor nuisance that we need to deselect "Stop on copy/rename" in Tortoise SVN). Note that we have a quite complex build system and several people also use git-svn. Still, no problems so far.